# What exactly this code I see in the example Word Add-Ins written in React do?

Tags: reactjs, office-addins

In the index.tsx file of many Office Word Add-In examples linked by the official documentation and in the projects created by Yeoman generator, I see following code at the bottom.

Can somebody explain what this code does, line by line? And why it is needed?

```
if ((module as any).hot) {
  (module as any).hot.accept("./components/App", () => {
    const NextApp = require("./components/App").default;
    render(NextApp);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the setup for the webpack [Hot Module Replacement plugin](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/)

this rerender `components/App` component when its source change during development

this plugin makes development iterations faster by not auto-reloading code changes and preserving internal application state